# Stop focusing editor when clicking "run code snippet"

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange, editor, stack-snippets

When creating a post that has one or more code snippets and I click "Run code snippet" the page scrolls back to the post's textarea. Since the code snippets are normally at the end of posts, this means each time I test the code I need to manually scroll all the way back to where I was.

This does not happen when editing a post.

Running the code is a frequent action when ensuring that code is free of bugs and at a standard I find acceptable. The need to scroll back to the result of the run is a major interruption of my work flow.

I find this to be the single most annoying feature on Stack Exchange sites.
Am I the only one that finds this feature annoying?

I request that this feature be removed, or that there be a way to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Thanks for logging this. It may need to be logged on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). There is a similar zombie post on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271824/run-code-snippet-focuses-on-textarea-after-copy-to-answer)

Comment: If a feature-request requests to remove a feature, was the feature still a feature or actually a bug?

Comment: @Mast, I think the term of art is "[Misfeature](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/misfeature)".  I have to admit to being surprised how old the word is, though...

Comment: I've been using [this userscript](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/Preview-Antifocus) for ages for this

Comment: Related, highly-upvoted Q on SO about this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295666/disable-annoying-autofocus-when-clicking-preview

Comment: This may be fixed with the new [Stacks editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033).

Answer (score 3):

You can stop this in two ways. To get the code to run on all pages automatically you can convert these to [userscript manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript_manager) scripts.

1. Disable the onclick events on the preview.

   ```
   $(".wmd-preview").off("click")
   ```
2. Wrap the buttons' onclick events to stop propagation.

   ```
   $(".snippet button.s-btn, .snippet .popout-code")
       .each((_, e) => {
           const handlers = ($._data(e, "events").click ?? []).map(c => c.handler);
           $(e).off("click").on("click", (event, ...args) => {
               event.stopPropagation();
               handlers.forEach(h => h(event, ...args));
           });
       })
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I already have a extension that does similar, I am migrating it to v3.0 (Manifest version 3) and dropped this option, forgetting how annoying it is. I posted because I think that it should be fixed for everyone.

Comment: @Blindman67 Ah! I like to click text when I'm reading, and so when I'm proofreading my answers... Aagh!!!